# Kill requirments-gathering and requirements-engineering

Tags: discussion, tags

The [requirments-gathering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/requirments-gathering) and [requirements-engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/requirements-engineering) tags were just added via the question [What is the difference between requirements Elicitation and Requirements Analysis in the real world?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/33722/what-is-the-difference-between-requirements-elicitation-and-requirements-analysis): the former is misspelled and the latter is a rephrase of the tags already on the question. Can these be killed?

Comment: Looks like they've been killed.

Comment: @Marcie they're not dead, they just don't have any questions in them because I untagged the only question that had them. They're still there and show up when you use tag autocompletion.

Comment: [Tags not associated with any question are pruned every 24 hours on the backend.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/what-happens-to-zombie-tags)

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhhhh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct. As long as the tags have been removed, and are not used in any "live" questions, they will be culled daily.